# How to navigation quickly to any page in commit page of Github webpage?

Tags: git, github

Before, I can change manual in the Address bar like:

https://github.com/facebook/yoga/commits/master?page=5

Currently, Github seems to change that.

So, when I want to navigation to page 53 of `Commit page in Github`. I must action with 53 clicks to `Older` button.

[image]

Too much time to do that. With repo have many commits like React. I can't do this.

Have many methods to resolved my problem.

Is:

- Tried to click 53 times. And save to bookmarks. That terrible!!!
- Using Github tools? Github tools are only available on Windows and Mac. And it very slow.
- Using a plugin in Sublime Text or Visual Code like `Git History`.

The almost method needs using software.

Have any another method to do direct in https://github.com ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `?page=5`.

Setting a page this way still works, but the url is not displayed this way.

You should be able to still use this to jump to a certain page in the commit history.

Comment: I've not tried it after the Github start change URL. Thanks @tehp

Comment: No problem @vanloc. It does look different, but everything seems to work the same :)